# SQL server average age in two different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, where I created two columns for 'female' and 'male'

```
SELECT
      ID,
      UserName,
      concat(FirstName,'  ',LastName) as Name,
      iif(substring(ID,10,1) % 2 =0,'Female', 'Male') as Gender
INTO NewUsers1
FROM   Users
```

Now, I want to get the Average age for both genders. I want to separate this into two columns named ' gender' and 'average age' with one row for 'female average age' and one row for 'male average age'

How can I do this?

The age is seen from the column ID, where the number is the date of birth.

```
ID 

500603-4268    <-- birth year is 3rd June 1950.
500607-6521    <-- birth year is 7th June 1950.
530407-7989    <-- birth year is 4th April 1953.
530720-7675
540430-4887
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: sample Data please -@Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you average ages in two columns without loosing other columns:

```
select
    *
,   avg(case when Gender = 'Male' then null else age end)   over(partition by Gender)   avgAge_Female
,   avg(case when Gender = 'Female' then null else age end) over(partition by Gender)       avgAge_Male
from
    (
    select
        f1.*
        ,    datediff(
            year
            ,   cast(
                concat(
                    concat('19', left(f1.vl, 2)) 
                    , '-'
                    ,   right(left(f1.vl, 4), 2) 
                    , '-'
                    ,    right(f1.vl, 2) 
                ) 
            as date)  
            ,   getdate()
            ) age
    from
        (
        select
            ID,
            UserName,
            concat(FirstName,'  ',LastName) as Name,
            left(ID, charindex('-', ID) - 1) vl,
            iif(substring(ID,10,1) % 2 =0,'Female', 'Male') as Gender
        from Users
        ) f1
    ) g1
```

**Edit**: Combined into one column version:

*Note*: *I've used subqueries to make it easy to understand so it is not an optimized query.*

```
select
    h1.ID
,   h1.UserName
,   h1.Name
,   h1.Gender
,   isnull(h1.avgAge_Male, h1.avgAge_Female) avgAge_MaleOrFemale
    from
        (
        select
                *
            ,   avg(case when Gender = 'Male' then null else age end)   over(partition by Gender)   avgAge_Female
            ,   avg(case when Gender = 'Female' then null else age end) over(partition by Gender)       avgAge_Male
            from
                (
                select
                    f1.*
                    ,    datediff(
                        year
                        ,   cast(
                            concat(
                                concat('19', left(f1.vl, 2)) 
                                , '-'
                                ,   right(left(f1.vl, 4), 2) 
                                , '-'
                                ,    right(f1.vl, 2) 
                            ) 
                        as date)  
                        ,   getdate()
                        ) age
                from
                    (
                    select
                        ID,
                        UserName,
                        concat(FirstName,'  ',LastName) as Name,
                        left(ID, charindex('-', ID) - 1) vl,
                        iif(substring(ID,10,1) % 2 =0,'Female', 'Male') as Gender
                    from Users
                    ) f1
                ) g1
        ) h1
```

Comment: Preferred is one column "average age" with one row for each gender

Comment: Please check the latest version. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Much appreciated. Last question is how to hide 'vl', 'avgAge_Female' and 'avgAge_Male' of the columns... ADD HIDDEN does not seem to work in this case

Comment: You can simply update the select part by writing desired columns rather than *. I've edited the answer, you can check.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks a lot for your assistance! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN substring(ID, 10, 1) % 2 = 0 THEN AGE END) as AVG_AGE_FEMALE,
       AVG(CASE WHEN substring(ID, 10, 1) % 2 = 1 THEN AGE END) as AVG_AGE_MALE
FROM Users;
```